# How to make gulp's fs.readFileSync get content first then use its data on gulp.src?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to concatenate all plugins js files into one, by referencing an external file named config.php which stores all of the required scripts.

However while doing that, encountered a problem as gulp.src function will run first with the empty array "arrayFiles" before fs.readFile finish reading the file and update the array.

Some codes are shown below

```
// gulp.js

var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var fs = require("fs");
var arrayFiles = new Array();
gulp.task('compressAllPlugins', function(done) {
    fs.readFile('path/to/config.php', {encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'rs'}, function(e, data) {
        if (e) return console.log(e);
        // codes to process content and convert it into array
        // arrayFiles.push(eachData);
    }
    console.log('arrayFiles: ',arrayFiles);
    gulp.src(arrayFiles)
    .pipe(plugins.uglify().on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(concat('myplugins.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app'))
    .on('end', done); 
    });
});
```

Below code shows the content of config.php

```
// config.php

<?php
return [
    'scripts' =>[
        'assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'assets/libs/angular/angular.js',
        'assets/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js'
    ]
];
```

From the above code, console.log gives the correct array of data as shown:

```
// output
arrayFiles: ['assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'assets/libs/angular/angular.js',
  'assets/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js']
```

However myplugins.min.js is not generated based on the array.

**Question**: How to make gulp.src runs AFTER fs.readFile updated arrayFiles? or any other way to workaround?

**Attempts:**

hardcode arrayFiles within the gulp.task and not using fs.readFile will read the respective files as inserted into the array.

```
// gulp.js (attempt #1)

var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var fs = require("fs");
var arrayFiles = new Array();
gulp.task('compressAllPlugins', function(done) {
    arrayFiles =[
        'public/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'public/assets/libs/angular/angular.js',
        'public/assets/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js'
    ];

    gulp.src(arrayFiles)
    .pipe(plugins.uglify().on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(concat('myplugins.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app'))
    .on('end', done); 
    });
});
```

This code able to generate myplugins.min.js as required with all the globs but it is not reading my config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh found my mistake:

After several review of the code found out that it DOES read the updated array just that the data being retrieved does not have 'public' directory in it hence myplugins.min.js is not generated.

```
// gulp.js

arrayFiles.push('public/'+eachData);
```